# How do I merge two Arrays of objects into one Set of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following result after a facet stage:

```
{
    directComputers: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('6139f794f6a0af371900dbfh'),
            name: MyComputer_1
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('6319bd1540b41d1a35717a16'),
            name: MyComputer_2
        }
    ],
    indirectComputers: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('6319bd1540b41d1a35717a16'),
            name: MyComputer_2
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('61f39f8ae2daa732deff6d90'),
            name: MyComputer_3
        }
    ]
```

I'm trying to add the objects from both arrays into a set (to avoid duplicates), and then unwind so I end up with one separate document for each object.

Like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6139f794f6a0af371900dbfh'),
    name: MyComputer_1
}
```

---

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6319bd1540b41d1a35717a16'),
    name: MyComputer_2
}
```

---

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('61f39f8ae2daa732deff6d90'),
    name: MyComputer_3
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objects inside your 2 arrays are completely identical(i.e. both `_id` and `name` is the same and contains no other fields), you can use `$setUnion` to construct the union. Then `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      allComputers: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$directComputers",
          "$indirectComputers"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$allComputers"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$allComputers"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f_4_RXmm3PG)

---

If you would rather compare with some key field, says `_id` in this case, you can use `$reduce` to construct the union.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      allComputers: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$indirectComputers",
          "initialValue": "$directComputers",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this._id",
                  "$$value._id"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$value",
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$allComputers"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$allComputers"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_OuYYscjq1t)

Comment: Yes that actually makes sense the second query. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the results unwinded you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$concatArrays: ["$directComputers", "$indirectComputers"]}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$group: {_id: "$data._id", name: {$first: "$data.name"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/veDbvtjh9Tk)

Another option is which is more generic (for cases where `$unwind` is not needed):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$setUnion: ["$directComputers", "$indirectComputers"]}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T6HtKhdtmHc)

Comment: `$setUnion` isn't working, when ObjectId is involved.